# Hide non source files from the Qt Creator (4.8) file system view

Tags: cmake, ide, filesystems, qt-creator, directory-structure

Qt Creator (4.2.1) used to do this by default. It would show the files organised in the same directory structure as they are in my file system, but it would only show files that are source or header files for the current project. It could work this out with the CMake `add_executable`, `add_library`, or `add_custom_target` function call.

The new version of Qt Creator now shows all the files in my file system, regardless of whether they are source or header files or not. I can change it from "File System" view to "Projects" view, but this structure the files in a different way to my directory structure, i.e it organises them into "Headers", "Targets", and "CMake Modules".

How can I get Qt Creator to behave more like the old version, and only show the files relevant to my project, but in the directory structure that they are actually in?

Thanks.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this in the qt developer forum.

Comment: @itisravi I have done now, thanks. The link is [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/104195/hide-non-source-files-from-the-qt-creator-4-8-file-system-view) but so far it is also unanswered.